# Using COUNTIFS instead of SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, substitution

I have a formula using `SUMPRODUCT` that gives me the row number if a set of conditions are met. As the file from where I fetch the data has *13 000* lines, it becomes time consuming.

Here is the `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((N30=Hierarchy!$B$1:$B$15000)*(D30>=Hierarchy!$I$1:$I$15000)*(D30<=Hierarchy!$J$1:$J$15000)*ROW(Hierarchy!$U$1:$U$15000))`

I am trying to substitute the previous formula using the below (through `COUNTIFS`) - why doesn't it work?

`=COUNTIFS(Hierarchy!$B$1:$B$15000, N30, Hierarchy!$I$1:$I$15000, "<="&D30, Hierarchy!$J$1:$J$15000,">="&D30)`

Comment: Does it work or fail with a subset of the data (i.e., 1 line? 10? 100?)?  If not, can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIFS will not return a row, it will return the number of matches found (there's only 1 match, right?). The MATCH formula will do what you're looking for:

```
=MATCH(1,(N30=$B$1:$B$15000)*(D30>=$I$1:$I$15000)*(D30<=$J$1:$J$15000),0)
```

This is an array formula, so you'll need to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it work.

I'm not sure how much time it'll save. If multiple rows match the criteria, the MATCH formula will display the first row while the SUMPRODUCT formula will display the sum of all matching rows.

EDIT: I got the MATCH formula from Contextures: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's what I was looking for.